# firefox add on can't be installed

Tags: firefox, xpi

I program firefox addon. I try to install xpi file from official tutorial and it works. I copy xpi file. I try to install copied xpi file. I don't change any files in the xpi file. The installation doesn't work. firefox says copied xpi file is not working. I don't change anything it's exactly the same file. Why doesn't this work:?

info: I found out that somebody had same problem. He copied the extracted folder that appeared after extracting xpi file. When he copied the content of the folder, it worked. I copy content of the folder all the time but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could literally be anything. Try running Firefox from the command line and installing the add-on. This way you can look for errors as they will be logged to the command line.

If you don't find anything then give us somewhere to download the add-on and maybe we will be able to help.